# JavaScript to JQuery, Converting a Sorting Gallery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I need to convert this working filter gallery from JavaScript JQuery. I'm a complete novice in both these languages so I was hoping someone could give me a little help. Below is the JavaScript that will have to be converted,

```
(function() {

var filterButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".filterList a");
imageNodes = document.querySelectorAll("img");

console.log(filterButtons, imageNodes);

function staggerImage() {
    TweenMax.staggerFromTo(imageNodes, 0.7, {opacity:0}, {opacity:1}, 0.3);
}

function doImageSwitch(event) {
    console.log("fire");
    console.log(event.target.parentNode.id);

    for(i=0; i<imageNodes.length; i++) {
            imageNodes[i].style.display = "inline";

        if(!imageNodes[i].classList.contains(event.target.parentNode.id)) {
            imageNodes[i].style.display = "none";
        }
    }
    staggerImage();
}

[].forEach.call(filterButtons, function(el) {
    el.addEventListener("click", doImageSwitch, false);
});

staggerImage();

})();
```

And this is the HTML code I have set up,

```
<?php 
include './includes/functions.php';

$conn = connect($config);
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT * FROM main_content");
//echo mysqli_num_rows($result); ?>

<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
  <head>

    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Filter Gallery</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/foundation.css" />
    <script src="js/vendor/modernizr.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.15.1/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

  </head>

  <body>

  <nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">Something</a></h1>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button with Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown filterList">
          <li id="flower"><a href="#">Flower </a></li>
          <li id="puppy" ><a href="#">Puppy  </a></li>
          <li id="kitten" ><a href="#">Kitty  </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns text-center">
        <div class="images">

            <?php
                while($row = $result -> fetch_assoc()) {
                    echo "<img class=\"{$row['img_class']} 
                           img-responsive\" src=\"img/{$row['img_src']}\" 
                           alt=\"{$row['img_alt']}\">";
                }
            ?>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(document).foundation();
</script>
<script src="js/myScript.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: StackOverflow is not a coding service.

Comment: @Mathletics simply looking for a good place to start.

Comment: jQuery is *not* a language. It's a framework written in and for Javascript. So the question basically doesn't make sense.

Comment: I guess this validates my novice knowledge on the topic. @IngoBürk

Comment: @IngoBürk, I think most people call it a library.. which is like splitting hairs a bit..

Comment: There shouldn't be any good reason to rewrite this in jQuery... Javascript is the basis of jQuery (as jQuery is a Library written in Javascript, as previously mentioned above)... If there was a good reason to do this I would help you, but there is absolutely none.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you write the javascript code yourself? If so it should not be a problem finding the answer. StackOverflow is as said not a coding service. I can try to help you, but I will not be wasting time on this question if it's for homework or some programming job ;)

If you first try to convert the code, I will be happy to help you (try).

---

the following uses an html structure that is presumably the same as your php echo output.

```js
(function() {
 
// Selecting all of the img tags within the document that have to be changed
var imageNodes = $(".images img");
 
// TweenMax syntax stays the same
function staggerImage() {
  TweenMax.staggerFromTo(imageNodes, 0.7, {opacity:0}, {opacity:1}, 0.3);
}
 
$(".filterList a").on("click", function(e) {
        console.log("fire");
 
        // parent() - http://api.jquery.com/parent/
        //console.log('This: %o - Parent - %o - ParentId - %o',  $(this),  $(this).parent(),  $(this).parent().attr("id"));        
        var parentId = $(this).parent().attr("id");
        // [parentId] will be used as a scoped variable on the nested anonymous function declared in [.each] below.
 
        // .each([array],func) | [array].each(func) - http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/
        $(imageNodes).each(function(index, value) {
            console.log("index: %o | value: %o | parentId: %o", index, value, parentId);
 
                // .hasClass([string]) - http://api.jquery.com/hasclass/
                if($(value).hasClass(parentId))
                {
                        $(value).css("display","inline");
                } else {
                        $(value).css("display","none");
                }
        });
   
    staggerImage();
});
 
staggerImage();
 
})();
```

```css
img {width:5em; height:5em;border:0.1em solid black;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="top-bar" data-topbar>
    <ul class="title-area">
      <li class="name">
        <h1><a href="#">Something</a></h1>
      </li>
      <li class="toggle-topbar menu-icon"><a href="#">Menu</a></li>
    </ul>

  <section class="top-bar-section">
    <!-- Right Nav Section -->
    <ul class="right">
      <li class="has-dropdown">
        <a href="#">Right Button with Dropdown</a>
        <ul class="dropdown filterList">
          <li id="flower"><a href="#">Flower </a></li>
          <li id="puppy" ><a href="#">Puppy  </a></li>
          <li id="kitten" ><a href="#">Kitty  </a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </section>
</nav>

<div class="row">
    <div class="small-12 columns text-center">
        <div class="images">

            <img class="flower img-responsive" src="img/test.png" alt="flower 1" />
            <img class="flower img-responsive" src="img/test.png" alt="flower 2" />
            <img class="puppy img-responsive" src="img/test.png" alt="puppy 1" />
            <img class="flower img-responsive" src="img/test.png" alt="flower 3" />
            <img class="kitten img-responsive" src="img/test.png" alt="kitten 1" />
            <img class="puppy img-responsive" src="img/test.png" alt="puppy 3" />

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

### jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/1m4LmLhx/1/

### pastebin: http://pastebin.com/bfDL5NLU

---

Note: when you click on the hyperlinks, that we've attached click event handlers to, the viewport is being directed back to the top of the page.. this is usually undesirable, but it seems to be outside of the scope of this question to address that behavior.

Comment: It was done in class with my professor actually! I can successfully change over and implement variables, but the for loop is stumping me. I've been working on this for way too long and have not gotten nearly as far as I should have. I'll show you what I have (its a gong show).

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/X1B8baP.png 

@thomasdarvik Here's this dismal piece of code, it's actually embarrassing.

Comment: Oh my god, I'm a brick. Haha, sorry about that. Here is what it looks like fired up in the browser. I have to use TweenMax within it too. I've been trying to familiarize myself with the proper syntax... but yea. It's rough.

Comment: http://imgur.com/Phsh2Sd

http://imgur.com/s5pgyHA

These are the images -- basically a simple dropdown that allows for sorting through the 15 images.

Comment: @SamGarcia, is there any particular instruction on whether you can use or change existing functions into anonymous functions?

Comment: @thomasdarvik, you seem to be fairly new as well.. where did the `.imageSelector` class you referenced to come from?

Comment: Yes, learning by helping is a concept that I like. I am really sorry, forgot about the .imageSelector class that I implemented (or that OP has to implement in the HTML-code). It is simply a class so that you don't have to use queryselector.

Comment: Given that OP's instructions were so unclear I also took the freedom to make my own classes in the HTML. @BrettCaswell

Comment: @thomasdarvik I completely agree brother, I genuinely just didn't know how to start. I'm a strong digital designer, backend code is my achilles heal :( Thank you so much for trying your hand at helping me, I appreciate it more than you know. -- Just a couple questions about your edit (excuse my lack of knowledge, but i really do want to understand) .. in the for loop, 'i' is changed to '$this', and the traditional way of writing out a for loop with the greater than symbol, specifying length, and ++ are taken out. Why is this? How does it still fire/cycle through the images properly?

Comment: @BrettCaswell The instructions are just as unclear as my initial post unfortunately. I'm sure I could use anon functions, as that's what he's (my prof) has been stressing for us to use.

Comment: jQuery has a .each() which removes the need for a "traditional" for()-loop. You can read more about it in the jQuery-documentation, but simply put;

"Iterate over a jQuery object, executing a function for each matched element."

Comment: @BrettCaswell You are free to edit my suggestion any time. I am really just trying to help this guy out. :)

Comment: @BrettCaswell Thank you so much for your help. I was getting some errors with the code you were able to write -- I changed some brackets around and it works at the beginning .. but when I go to filter each, all images are gone. In order for me to return the corresponding images, would i have to change something within the FilterList or the array? 

http://pastebin.com/bqQ827wB

Comment: @SamGarcia, you're correct.. I did not use `.each` properly.. and `id` is not a method in `parent()`. I'll post a correction..

Comment: @SamGarcia, apart from that: look at your html markup.. `$(this).parent('filterList').id` couldn't possibly be correct (even if `parent().id` existed).. you want the `id` of the `li` that is the direct parent of the hyperlink `a`. `$(this).parent().attr("id")` is the correct way.

Comment: While I'm glad you are all helping Sam, if this is his homework I hope he's going to go study the jQuery API pages some more rather than trolling SO for answers to his assigned homework.

Comment: You're absolutely right. I am just trying to help a fellow student out ;)

Comment: @Mike, I totally agree. critical thinking lessons and assignments - like this one - can be quite beneficial. you can get more out of giving a 'rationalized' incorrect answer then simply providing the correct answer.  It's about reflecting on the false logic in your rationality that lead to the wrong answer, and addressing that.  @SamGarcia, read and gain familiarity with the API.. in particular, review `$().live` and `$().delegate`. see whether they are applicable..